# I have warnings when I pull from git to Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I uploaded a very simple and legit code and it is correct, but when I pull from another computer the XML files are colored red
Both computers with the same version of the software
All words that start with

android,

app:layout,

tools:... is red

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="69dp"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.809" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What is the warning you are getting?

Comment: onley red line.

Comment: Attribute android:id is not allowed here

Comment: Attribute app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf is not allowed here

Comment: Check your IDE configuration. if android studio configuration are different on both systems then it will give these kind of errors.

Comment: try removing and android namespace adding again

Answer (score -1):

Removing namespaces and adding again worked for me.

If it didn't work try

- Files->Sync Project with Gradle Files
- File->Invalidate Caches/ Restart->Invalidate and Restart

If none of them works check if you've the correct SDK versions installed